# How can I capture request data in a static list

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, web, servlet-3.0

I am having a URL for e.g:

```
http://some_url.suffix?data=test1.
```

I will be having multiple request of the sort:

```
http://some_url.suffix?data=test1
http://some_url.suffix?data=test2
http://some_url.suffix?data=test3
http://some_url.suffix?data=test4
```

I want to maintain a static list at server side which will contain data received from requests across all sessions

```
List<String> data;
```

List will contain data1,data2,data3,data4. List will be cleared after particular interval and new list will be used for subsequent requests.
What is the best option to achieve this:

```
1. static List<String> data = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
2. Singleton wrapper class to perform operation on normal java.util.List
3. using synchronized block
```

Comment: `data.add(request.getParameter('data'))`?

Comment: that is obvious one, but I want to know the best way i.e. static declaration of data or something else.

Comment: How do u declare data when it's sent from clients? If you know what the data is, you don't need to get it from clients, if you don't then you have to capture it from the request.

Comment: I am talking about the list maintained at server end which will contain all data from all requests, across sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st solution can cause a performance issues as the array would be copied on every incoming request.

3rd solution is better, just remember that intrinsic lock should also be static object on your controller/service. This also require to remember of synchonized block every time when touching `data` so probably this isn't best solution neither.

2nd option is the best solution for that case imo. Create singleton that store `data` internally and provide `synchronized` method to play with it. The synchronization stuff will be closed inside one class.

My attempt to implementation of that singleton wrapper would looks like:

```
//Use enum to have singleton provided by jvm
enum DataCache {

    INSTANCE;

    //Use LinkedList if you expecting many calls. The insertion will be much faster.
    private List<String> data = new LinkedList<>();

    synchronized void add(String value) {
        data.add(value);
    }

    /*
     * Returns defensive copy, so that no one has reference to this.data.
     * If data is fetched only on clear you can make this private instead of synchronized 
     * (or even better get rid of it and create defensive copy inside clear()).
     */
    synchronized List<String> get() {
        return new ArrayList<>(data); 
    }

    /*
     * Returns last snapshot of data to keep consistency.
     */
    synchronized List<String> clear() {
        List<String> lastSnapshot = get();
        data = new LinkedList<>();
        return lastSnapshot;
    }
}
```

Then you can use `INSTANCE.add()` in method that handle request and `INSTANCE.clear()` in the scheduler.

**Note** I don't know how do you play with gathered data, but consider other collection than list. If number of particular data occurrences isn't important it would be better to replace `List` with `Set` and `HashSet` implementation. (Like when you received `data=test1` twice and you care only that test1 cames no matter how many times). If you care about numbers you could also consider map of values to number of occurences.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Singleton service with a method

```
public boolean addKey(String key, String value);
```

Then in your service I would use a HashMap>

```
private static Map<String, List<String>> keysMap;

private Map<String, List<String>> getKeysMap(){
    synchronized (this){        
        if(keysMap == null){
            keysMap = new HashMap();
        }
        return keysMap; 
    }
}

public void addKey(String key, String value){
    List<String> keyParams = getKeysMap().get(key);
    if(keyParams == null){
        keyParams = new ArrayList();
    }  
    //decide here if you want to store repeated values
    keyParams.add(param);
    getKeysMap().put(key, keyParams);
}
```

Comment: The whole point of the question was thread safety and you provided solution that isn't thread safe at all. Btw. what is a key and what is a value?

Comment: ahh sorry i forgot that, you only need to add the synchronized keyword to the method add and getKeyMap.

Comment: They key would be your "data" parameter, and the list would store all yours parameter values test1,test2,...